# How can I turn a select statement that includes an except into an Ordered table?

Tags: sql

Here is my example:

```
select * into temp from 
      select *, 'I' as flag from (
            select * from A
            except 
            select * from B ) a
      union
      select *, 'D' as flag  from (
            select * from B
            except 
            select * from A ) b
ORDER BY X1,X2
```

Comment: You question doesn't make sense.

Comment: ?? just use column numbers ?? eg `order by 1,2`

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer -

select * into dbo.temp from 
      (select *, 'I' as flag from (
            select * from dbo.A
            except 
            select * from dbo.B ) a
      union
      select *, 'D' as flag  from (
            select * from dbo.B
            except 
            select * from dbo.A ) b
) as C
ORDER BY X1,X2

-- Remove temp table after use
DROP TABLE temp